# glibc memory alloction : arenas and debugging

Tags: linux, debugging, glibc

Recent versions of glibc ( from 2.12 ? ) have tunable MALLOC_ARENA_MAX and MALLOC_PER_THREAD.

Questions :

1. Is there any difference between MALLOC_PER_THREAD=0 and MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=1 ?
   Is MALLOC_PER_THREAD still supported in the latest glibc ?
2. Arenas increases virtual memory usage : are suitable for 32 bit kernels ?
3. Are they suitable also for one core cpu (virtual guests) ?
4. If I enable memory checks with

> MALLOC_CHECK_=3

does glibc use a basic debugging allocator or the default one ?

Once upon a time I read glibc with certain kind of debug use a basic allocator instead the regular one ... but I cannot find the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As I understand it, `MALLOC_PER_THREAD` was a temporary configuration knob provided on RHEL to enable the new per-thread allocator (see [the corresponding CentOS release notes](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.4/Release_Notes/Tools.html) for details). It is no longer available in current releases of `glibc`, and the new allocator became the default in 2.15 (I think). Setting `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=1` means there can only be one arena, which has a similar effect but is probably not strictly equivalent since other parts of the “new” allocator are still active in this case.
2. Yes, they are suitable for 32-bit kernels; but the default tuning is different (`M_ARENA_TEST` is 2 on 32-bit systems, 8 on others).
3. There probably isn’t much point to using multiple arenas on single-core systems, but the default tuning should take care of that (the hard limit for arenas is usually a multiple of the number of available CPUs).
4. `M_CHECK_ACTION=3` is the default nowadays, so enabling memory checks uses the default allocator.

The user-level documentation for this is in [man mallopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html).

glibc 2.26 [should have a new per-thread cache](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS;hb=HEAD), [tcache](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2017-01/msg00524.html), but that will obviously take a little while before it’s available in distributions. (The planned release date is August 1 this year).

Comment: Doubt : RHEL MALLOC_PER_THREAD or the new glibc 2.26 per-thread cache : does it mean they are useful also with one core but multi-threaded applications ?

Comment: 4. Where can I find info on older glibc and different behaviour / default value of MALLOC_CHECK_ ?

Comment: The per-thread pools should still be useful on single-core CPUs with multi-threaded applications, because they’d still reduce contention. You’d need to benchmark your specific applications to be sure though. To find older behaviours, run `man mallopt` on the systems in question — that will give you historically relevant documentation.